# Twitter crawler: why does the memory grow?

Tags: performance, memory, twitter, web-crawler

I have been trying to crawl Twitter via the Streaming API and by filtering the retrieved tweets by keywords/hashtags/users.

Here is my example using [HBC](https://github.com/twitter/hbc) (although the same problem happens with Twitter4J):

```
// After connection:
final BlockingQueue<String> queue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(10000);

StatusesFilterEndpoint filterQuery = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();
filterQuery.followings(myListOfUserIDs);
filterQuery.trackTerms(myListOfKeywordsAndHashtags);

final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4);

Runnable tweetAnalyzer = defineRunnable(queue);
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_THREADS; i++)
    executor.execute(tweetAnalyzer);
```

where the analyzer `tweetAnalyzer` is returned by:

```
private Runnable defineRunnable(final BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
    return new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true)
                try {
                    System.out.println(queue.take());
                } 
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

    };
}
```

However, the process continues to grow in memory.

Two questions:

1. How to design this crawler properly, so that it does not grow in memory and does not saturate the RAM?
2. How to select the best queue length (here set to `10000`) so that it does not saturate? I have seen that using this length the queue continues to be full of tweets (it never goes empty) and I am able to crawl 700 tweets/min, which is huge)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit hard to determine from the snippets that you provide. Do you register StatusesFilterEndpoint correctly?

I would recommend that you write a separate thread to monitor the size of the queue.

Obvious you are not able to proceed all the twitter messages you download. So you can only:

1. reduce the number of tweets you download by filtering more aggressively
2. Sample the input by throwing away every n message.
3. use a faster machine although for the tweetAnalyzer you display in the question this might not help.
4. deploy on a cluster

Comment: "Deploy on a cluster" might be the best option :)